# npgsql 3.0.5 won't run on Majorsilence reporting

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm using nppgsql 2.2.x version for 1 year but yesterday I tried to use 3.0.5.

I added reference to new library and all Database extraction run perfect but I found big problem with `Majorsilence` Reporting. No report will appear.

When using version 2.2.x all reports run.

Now I run on 4.0 framework and I read that it is not possible to use a framework little then 4.5 (but it run on 4.0!).

What could be the problem in your mind? Could it be the target framework?
Could it be some changes in 3.x version?

Do you have any ideas? I don't want to use 2.2.x version forever.

Thanks

Comment: You have to provide more info - is any exception thrown at any point, what exactly is the relationship between majorsilence and npgsql in your code, etc. In any case, it isn't supposed to be possible to run Npgsql on .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. .. npgsql want 4.5 .net And majorsilence run on 4.0